# ¿Cómo puedo listar todos los procesos en Linux por medio de rangos? (Rango solicitado por el usuario)

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, awk

**Resultado deseado:** 
**Rango 1-10**
PID        COMMAND        MEMORY
1          firefox        25MB
2          discord        18MB
5          chrome         50MB

Total Memoria:            93MB

**Rango 11-20**
PID        COMMAND        MEMORY
12         spotify        35MB
18         opera          35MB

Total Memoria:            70MB

**Rango 91-100**
PID        COMMAND        MEMORY
97         zoom           125MB
100        vim            30MB

Total Memoria:            155MB

(Y así sucesivamente con los demás procesos en ejecución)

---

```
(He intentado con esto pero no me imprime nada)

function print() {
    total=$(ps ax | wc -l) #Cuenta el número de procesos
    inicio=1 #Contador = 1
    rango2=$rango #Se copia la variable rango

    for i in seq 1 $total #For para todos los procesos
    do
        echo "( $inicio ... $rango2 )" >> procesos.txt
        for j in seq $inicio $rango2
        do
            if [ $j -eq $rango2 ]; then cadena+="$j"
            elif [ $j -lt $rango2 ];  then cadena+="$j,"
            fi
        done
        ps -p "$cadena" -o pid, cmd, vsize --sort=vsize >>  procesos.txt
        echo "" >> procesos.txt
        inicio=expr $rango2 + 1 #Siguiente rango + 1
        rango2=expr $rango2 + $1 #Total del rango +1 al ejecutarse (sumadora)
        cadena="" #Se vacía la cadena
    done
}
```

Comment: Usa Awk para filtrar. Por ejemplo, `ps aux| awk '1<=$2 && $2<=10'` para los que tienen PID entre 1 y 10. Lo suyo sería que explicaras exactamente lo que intentaste (con palabras además de código que ya pusiste) y qué te falta

Comment: ¿Cuál será el propósito de este script? ¿Presentar la información de manera amigable al usuario o mandarla a otra herramienta para parsearla? De ello depende la complejidad del script y su implementación.

Answer (score 1):

Algo como esto podría servirte:

```
ps aux | awk '1<=$2 && $2<=1000' | perl -e '
use strict;
use warnings;

sub mb {int((shift)/1024) . " MB"}

my @lines;
while (<>) {push @lines, $_}

my $comando_simple = 0;

my $cols = ("(\\S++)\\h*+" x ($comando_simple ? 11 : 10)) . "(.*)";
my ($mb, $s1, $s2) = (0, 3, 6);

for (@lines) {
    $_ =~ qr/^\h*$cols$/ or die;
    $s1 = length(   $2) > $s1 ? length(   $2) : $s1;
    $s2 = length(mb $6) > $s2 ? length(mb $6) : $s2;
}

sub fila {printf "%-*s%-*s%s\n", $s1+2, shift, $s2+2, shift, shift}

fila "PID", "MEMORY", "COMMAND";
for (@lines) {
    $_ =~ qr/^\h*$cols$/ or die;
    fila $2, mb($6), $11;
    $mb += $6;
}

print "\n\nTotal memoria: " . mb($mb) . "\n";
'
```

Utilizamos `awk` para filtrar las líneas por el rango de PID y `perl` para filtrar las columnas, imprimirlas en formato tabla con datos alineados y para calcular el total de MB.

Por defecto incluyo toda la columna del comando. Puedes obtener una salida simplificada del comando cambiando la variable perl: `$comando_simple = 1` por `$comando_simple = 0`. De esta manera, todo lo que haya dentrás del primer espacio del comando se excluye.

Nota: Estoy asumiendo que PID se encuentra en la columna 2, Memoria (resident) en la 6 y el comando en la 11, basándome en la salida de ps aux en una debian reciente. Podría pasar que en otra versión de `ps` la salida fuera algo distinta. O también si lo ejecutas via Cygwin. En tal caso deberás adaptar el script.